# Xamarin Forms, button not load second page

Tags: android, google-maps, button, xamarin

I have a problem with loading a second page. If I debug the whole project, Google Maps do not show, but if I debug with other XML. I mean I add label without anything, everything works fine. If I debug the project on a second page, Google Maps work.

Second page:

```
public Mapciorek()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MyMapa.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(Convert.ToDouble(13.0291), Convert.ToDouble(80.2083)), Distance.FromMiles(0.3)));
}
```

XML:

```
<ScrollView>
    <maps:Map 
        x:Name="MyMapa"
        IsShowingUser="true"
        MapType="Hybrid" HasZoomEnabled="True" />
</ScrollView>
```

App:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

First page (main page):

```
async private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Mapciorek());
}
```

Comment: don't do MoveToRegion in the constructor, there is no guarantee the map has loaded and been initialized at that point.  Move that code to OnAppearing

Comment: So where exactly i have to move it? Thanks for answer

Comment: I told you that, OnAppearing

Comment: still not works

Comment: I was pointing out bad code, not necessarily answering your question.  That's why I posted a comment.

Comment: Ok ok, but maybe you know why it not works?